# How to convert JSON data into pascal VOC format?

Tags: json

I wanted to convert JSON data into Pascal VOC format.

this is my json file format:

```
[
{
"Frame_count":1,
output:[
{
"Objects_classname":"car1",
"x_val":313.52719,
"y_val":325.85834,
"width":210.02463,
"height":201.64935
},

{
"Objects_classname":"person1",
"x_val":992.84949,
"y_val":277.18243,
"width":64.80127,
"height":210.47083
},

],
"Total_objects_detected":2,
}
]
```

I want is above json data needs to be converted into Pascal_VOC format.
Here x_val means xmin and y_val means ymin & xmin+width will be xmax  similarly, ymin+height will be ymax. and other data in pascal_VOC like

```
pose = unspecified,
truncated = 0
folder and filename,path will be any junk data.
database = unknown
size of frame = 1280 * 720
segmented = 0
name = class name from json file
difficult = 0
```

Comment: Choose a language, choose a library reading json in that language. Start coding. Code : read file and assign data, deserialize that data in pascal_VOC format. Python seems like a good bet https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html  and https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.html. If you have problems with your code once it is written come back to StackOverflow.

Comment: Can you show the expected output based on your input JSON sample?

Comment: @oliv This a example Pascal_voc format : <annotation><folder>img_out</folder><filename>0.jpg</filename><path>/home/administrator/Desktop/roadobj_demo/img_out/0.jpg</path><source><database>Unknown</database></source><size><width>1280</width><height>720</height><depth>3</depth></size><segmented>0</segmented><object><name>car1</name><pose>Unspecified</pose><truncated>0</truncated>
<difficult>0</difficult>
  <bndbox>
   <xmin>86.79452054794518</xmin>
   <ymin>200.02739726027397</ymin>
   <width>309.0</width>
   <height>187.0</height>
  </bndbox>
 </object> </annotation>

Comment: any idea how to do it?

Comment: https://github.com/canerkaraguler/Json2PascalVOC